# In a simple script to return the minimum of a list in scheme only the first value of the list is being returned by my solution. What's the bug?

Tags: list, scheme

```
(define (minim lst)
  (COND
   ((NULL? (CDR lst)) (CAR lst))
   (< (CAR lst) (minim (CDR lst)) (CAR lst))
  (ELSE (minim (CDR lst))))
  )
```

> (minim '(3 4 2 9 3 8))
>   3

I've figured out that it is the second line that is being evaluated and returning the (CAR of any list). What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis in the second condition. This makes the "<" operator operate over three elements rather than two. The correct code looks like:

```
(define (minim lst)
    (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
          ((< (car lst) (minim (cdr lst))) (car lst))
          (else (minim (cdr lst)))) )


(minim '(3 4 2 9 3 8))
```

One note though: This code is *not tail recursive*. It goes all the way to the end of the list and starts comparing from there (i.e., the last element is compared with the one before that and so on).

A more efficient implementation would compare the first element to the current minimum, then proceed forward processing a shorter list every time. If you go this way, you will need an additional function argument holding the current minimum (this is equivalent to a left fold rather than the right fold you have implemented).

Comment: You're right on both points. Also, I take apart the list twice as it is (to compare and to return a value). Thanks!